# Can a safety deposit box fee reduce my taxes if I don't itemize?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, safe-deposit-box

Suppose I make $100 interest from a bank account and I pay $100 for a safety deposit box in a given tax year where I take the standard deduction. Can the safety deposit box fee reduce my taxes somehow? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IRS Publication 17 *Your Income Tax* says on page 203 (in regard to
what you can deduct on Schedule A as an *itemized* deduction)

> You can deduct safe deposit box rent if you use the box to store taxable income-producing stocks, bonds, or investment-related papers and documents. You cannot deduct the rent if you use the box only for jewelry, other personal items, or tax-exempt securities.

If you are taking the standard deduction, you get no *additional* tax advantage
from your rental fee even if it *is* used solely for storage of investment
property and documents. The tax advantage is incorporated into the standard
deduction.

Answer (score 0):

The new tax code, effective 2018, removes the miscellaneous deductions this fell under, even if you itemized.